# Troubles with selection and nested ListBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selection

### Introduction

First I apologise for the vague title, but I couldn't think of a better way to put it for the question I pose:

I am developing a C#/WPF application and have a situation of needing to display a nested list structure in the UI. There is an list of objects that should be displayed, but each of those objects has a sub-list (possibly empty) of objects that must be displayed in a nested manner. To achieve this I am using a `ListBox` which has an item template containing a nested `ListBox` to display the sub-list.

I have achieved the goal of ensuring that only one item can be selected at once (whether that is an outer or inner item), but I'm now struggling with the following two issues that I require some help on:

1. I need a way to disable the selection of certain items, as well as the highlighting on mouse over, but without disabling all the internal UI elements. In the example below this would be disabling the selection/highlighting of the entries with red text, as well as the sub-list of this entry, but still able to see the `ToolTip` when hovering over the text.
2. Disabling the highlighting of an outer `ListBoxItem` when the mouse is over an internal `ListBoxItem` from the sub-list. Thus there will only ever be a highlight over one `ListBoxItem` at a time, though highlighting the outer `ListBoxItem` may draw the highlight over the inner sub-list as well.

---

### Example

Below are the two files needed to run the example I have put together:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        x:Name="TopLevelWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <ScrollViewer>
      <ScrollViewer.Resources>
         <local:InvertConverter x:Key="InvertConverter"/>

         <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Items}" x:Key="ItemsView">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
               <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="BoolProperty" Direction="Descending"/>
               <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Text" Direction="Ascending"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
         </CollectionViewSource>

         <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <DockPanel Margin="4,4,2,4"
                       LastChildFill="True">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                          ToolTip="ERROR"
                          ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding BoolProperty,
                                                             Converter={StaticResource InvertConverter}}">
                  <TextBlock.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BoolProperty}" Value="False">
                              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                           </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                     </Style>
                  </TextBlock.Style>
               </TextBlock>
               <ListBox x:Name="InnerListBox"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=TopLevelWindow,
                                               Path=DataContext.SelectedInnerItem}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        MouseEnter="InnerListBox_MouseEnter"
                        MouseLeave="InnerListBox_MouseLeave"/>
            </DockPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ScrollViewer.Resources>

      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsView}}"
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOuterItem}"
               BorderThickness="0"/>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private OuterClass _selectedOuterItem;
      private string _selectedInnerItem;

      public ObservableCollection<OuterClass> Items { get; set; }
      public OuterClass SelectedOuterItem
      {
         get { return _selectedOuterItem; }
         set
         {
            if (_selectedOuterItem != value)
            {
               _selectedOuterItem = value;
               _selectedInnerItem = null;
               PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedOuterItem)));
               PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedInnerItem)));
            }
         }
      }
      public string SelectedInnerItem
      {
         get { return _selectedInnerItem; }
         set
         {
            if (_selectedInnerItem != value)
            {
               _selectedInnerItem = value;
               _selectedOuterItem = null;
               PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedInnerItem)));
               PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedOuterItem)));
            }
         }
      }

      public MainWindow()
      {
         Items = new ObservableCollection<OuterClass>()
         {
            new OuterClass("Beep", true, new List<string>()
            {
               "Beep - A",
               "Beep - B",
               "Beep - C"
            }),
            new OuterClass("Boop", true, new List<string>()
            {
               "Boop - A",
               "Boop - B"
            }),
            new OuterClass("Baap", false, new List<string>()),
            new OuterClass("Biip", true, new List<string>()),
            new OuterClass("Buup", false, new List<string>()
            {
               "Buup - A",
               "Buup - B",
               "Buup - C",
               "Buup - D",
               "Buup - E"
            })
         };
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void InnerListBox_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
      {
         ListBox listBox = e.Source as ListBox;
         if (listBox != null)
         {
            OuterClass dc = listBox.DataContext as OuterClass;
            if (dc != null)
            {
               dc.MouseOverInternal = true;
            }
         }
      }

      private void InnerListBox_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
      {
         ListBox listBox = e.Source as ListBox;
         if (listBox != null)
         {
            OuterClass dc = listBox.DataContext as OuterClass;
            if (dc != null)
            {
               dc.MouseOverInternal = false;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public class OuterClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      private bool _mouseOverInternal;

      public string Text { get; set; }
      public bool BoolProperty { get; set; }
      public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
      public bool MouseOverInternal
      {
         get { return _mouseOverInternal; }
         set
         {
            if (_mouseOverInternal != value)
            {
               _mouseOverInternal = value;
               PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MouseOverInternal)));
            }
         }
      }

      public OuterClass(string x, bool y, IEnumerable<string> z)
      {
         Text = x;
         BoolProperty = y;
         Items = new ObservableCollection<string>(z);
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }

   public class InvertConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         return foo(value);
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         return foo(value);
      }

      private bool? foo(object val)
      {
         bool? boolVal = val as bool?;
         if (boolVal.HasValue)
         {
            return !boolVal.Value;
         }
         return null;
      }
   }
}
```

---

### What I've tried & conclusion

So far I have tried the following:

- Disabling the `ListBoxItem` elements where `BoolProperty` is set to `False`. This provided the desired behaviour except for the fact that the `ToolTip` on the internal `TextBlock` was also disabled.
- Using the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event on the internal `ListBox` elements and use that to set properties on the outer `ListBoxItem` elements. I was unable to achieve the desired behaviour through any property I tried setting, the code for the handling of these events is still present in the example above.
- Using the `Focusable` property on the outer `ListBoxItem` elements. While this disabled selection of those elements, and allowed the `ToolTip` on the inner `TextBlock` to be displayed, it did still highlight the items. This seems promising, as long as the highlighting can be removed, as I can simply disable the internal `ListBox` on the same trigger.

I would appreciate any help that can be provided. I am willing to use a different `ItemsControl` if need be, but would prefer to keep with the `ListBox` or a `ListView` if possible.